# Headings not rendering correctly in nextjs

Tags: next.js, markdown

I am creating a security blog where I upload write ups of hack the box machines I solve. I am using GraphQL as a cms and NextJS. I set the content of the entry to be a markdown file in the schema, then I use `react-markdown` to render that markdown. It does get rendered properly however the headings are all the same size. How do I make it so the headings are the correct size.

This is my [slug].js file

```js
import { GraphQLClient, gql } from "graphql-request";
import {MarkdownRenderer} from '../../components/MarkdownRenderer';

const graphcms = new GraphQLClient(<endpoint>);

const QUERY = gql`
query MyQuery($slug: String!) {
    entry(where: {slug: $slug}) {
      slug
      title
      description
      content
      coverImage {
        url
      }
    }
  }
  
`;

const SLUGLIST = gql`
{
    entries {
        slug
    }
}`

export async function getStaticPaths(){
    const {entries} = await graphcms.request(SLUGLIST);
    return {
        paths: entries.map((entry) => ({params: {slug: entry.slug}})),
        fallback: false,
    };
}

export async function getStaticProps( {params}) {
    const slug = params.slug;
    const data = await graphcms.request(QUERY, {slug});
    const entry = data.entry;
    return {
        props: {
            entry,
        },
    };  
}

export default function BlogPost({entry}){
    return (
        <main className=" w-1/2">
            <div className="mx-auto">
                <h1>{entry.title}</h1>
                <img src={entry.coverImage.url} className="w-1/5"/>
                <h4>{entry.description}</h4>
                <MarkdownRenderer markdownText={entry.content} />
            </div>
            
        </main>
    )
}
```

This is my markdown renderer component

```js
import ReactMarkdown from 'react-markdown';
export const MarkdownRenderer = ({ markdownText }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ReactMarkdown>{markdownText}</ReactMarkdown>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: I hate to be that guy, but why overcomplicate everything for a simple blog? Just use Github Pages (which uses Jekyll) or something like [Astro](https://astro.build/) – both have Markdown support built-in...

Comment: I tried using GitHub pages but it failed the build process so I just used vercel which was recommended by many people.